# Notification Builder (this) problems android

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have this object:

```
public  void timerDistraction(final View view) {

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
         //Do something after time
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                   "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
              .setContentTitle("Basic Notification")
              .setContentText("This is my example of basic notification")
              .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).build();
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getNotificationManager();
            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
            Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notificationSound);
            r.play();

     }
     }, 5000);
```

And the line

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
```

Has an error, presumably because of the (this)

Can anyone point me in the right direction. I've tried changing it to the function or null, but no progress. If I have just the notification code itself, without the delay, it works.

Comment: Where you called this  `timerDistraction(.....) `? from  `Activity ` or  `Fragment `

Comment: `timerDistraction` is not an object but method, `Notification.Builder()`  takes `Context` as argument, so you need pass something which inherits context ie, current `Activity`. what is calling `timerDistraction` and what inherit class where method is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are in the `Runnable`, `this` became the `Runnable` and not the `context` of your `Activity`. Since you must pass a `context` as [parameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#Notification.Builder%28android.content.Context%29), it triggers an error. To get the correct `context`, you can use the same way as the one you used for the `Toast`:

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

In this case, you will effectively pass your `Activity` `context` and not your `Runnable`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a fool for not seeing that. I'm still fairly new and up against a deadline, too. Thanks again